# Partitioning a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I would like to find out how to modify the contents of a list, specifically filenames which have been returned by `os.listdir()`.

The filenames consist of a number of duplicate names followed by an underscore, then a suffix, and then the file extension. I'm trying to cut the elements in the list down to just the first part of the filename, before the `'_'`, so:

```
apple_d.jpg
apple_si.jpg
apple_sg.jpg
```

becomes just a single entry in the list, `'apple'`.

I'm able to get rid of duplicates and re-alphabetise with

```
list(sorted(set(t)))
```

but getting rid of everything from the underscore onwards is proving tricky. I tried to do this via `.rpartition("_")[0]`. but that apparently doesn't work for lists. So I'm wondering how to go about this?

edit:  well, not working here. Still getting duplicates and no splitting.

```
objects = os.listdir(dir)





    for object in objects:
        sorted(set(object.split('_', 1)[0]))
        cmds.menuItem(label = object, parent = "objectMenu")
```

(The last command is a maya command, which populates an option menu). Very tired now so I'll have to take this up later. But thanks so much for the help to date. Sure to get this soon.

Comment: I'm guessing you're not looking for `os.path.commonprefix` ... but it seems like it's close to what you want, so I'll mention it here.

Comment: @mgilson: `commonprefix` is for *path components* (so separated by `os.sep`), not filenames.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- The docs say that it works character-by-character.  I don't see any reason why it can't work for filenames.

Comment: @mgilson: And just back from a beer festival, I in turn misremembered how `commonprefix` works..

Comment: Are you expecting there to be only **one** `_` underscore in the filename? If there are multiple, should the split be done on the first, or the last underscore?

Answer (score 6):

Use [`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) or [`str.rsplit()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) with a limit, then select the first element:

```
filename.split('_', 1)[0]
```

`.rsplit('_', 1)` will split on the last underscore, `.split()` on the first. Pick the one that fits your usecase best.

This gives you everything before the first or last underscore for that filename.

Using this in a set comprehension, with `sorted()` returning a list from that set:

```
unique_prefixes = sorted({filename.split('_', 1)[0] for filename in os.listdir(somedir)})
```

For Python 2.6 and earlier, where you don't yet have a set comprehension syntax, the following generator expression with `set()` would work too:

```
unique_prefixes = sorted(set(filename.split('_', 1)[0] for filename in os.listdir(somedir)))
```

Comment: @mgilson: The set comprehension is slightly more compact than the `set()` plus generator expression.

Comment: @mgilson: The set comprehension eliminates duplicates.  List comprehension does not.

Comment: Oh right.  I must be off my game today.  removing duplicates ... thanks.  (I've now deleted my silly and incorrect comment above).

Comment: Did you mean to use `rsplit`? Won't this break if the "prefix" contains an underscore? Of course, `rsplit` would break if the suffix contained an underscore, and I think you're doomed if both the prefix and suffix contain one.

Comment: @jpmc26: No, it is not clear from the question; I interpreted the suffix to *not* include any underscores. If both the suffix and prefix contain underscores you need much more complex rules to determine which is which.

Comment: I'm hanging in there guys, digesting this info. Python noob here so I'm moving kindof slow.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of the question, you tried to call `rpartition` directly on the list (perhaps like `os.listdir('path').rpartition('_')[0]`). I believe that to use `rpartition` in the manner you intend, you need to apply it to individual elements of the list. A list comprehension is the most recommended way to do this:

```
file_prefixes = [f.rpartition('_')[0] for f in os.listdir('path')]
```

Turning it into a set comprehension as Martijin Pieters suggests will eliminate duplicates:

```
file_prefixes = {f.rpartition('_')[0] for f in os.listdir('path')}
```

Note: This should actually be equivalent to Martijin Pieters' answer, just using `rpartition` as mentioned in the question instead of `rsplit`. (Basically saves you the `1` parameter.)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me guys-

```
labels = os.listdir(dir)




labels_processed=[]
for label in labels:
    labels_processed.append(label.split('_')[0])



labprocessed  = set(labels_processed)



for finallab in labprocessed:        
    cmds.menuItem(label = finallab, parent = "objectMenu")
```

Cheers,

S Tozer

Answer (score 0):

Referred answer by [Martjin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) but instead of using split I used rpartition as was specifically interested in comparing 1st part of the string before the last occurrence of searched string/character -

```
if x not in sorted({filename.rpartition(' - ')[0] for filename in os.listdir(somedir)}):
     some action...
```